# How to consume a gradle project with its dependencies?

Tags: java, spring, rest, gradle, spring-boot

I have a REST Web service API code with me as a Spring Boot Application using gradle to download the dependencies.
I want to consume this project within my another project by making the JAR out of the REST API and then use this project, but I am getting exceptions as the JARS used in REST project which are defined in the build.gradle of that project are not available in my project when I extracted it as a JAR.

How can I consume this REST API code with its dependencies into my new project?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to consume the REST API as a client ? If so, you don't need to add the jar to your project. Just run the spring boot separately and use the URL of the REST service for your client. Your client project just needs the URL to hit the service.

Comment: No , i have the code for the REST API and i have to include it as a JAR only . but an ambiguity as on how to get the gradle dependencies of the API in my consumer code.?